# Ensure "this" context within prototype method

Tags: javascript

For `prototype` methods, is there a safe way to ensure `this` is always the object itself (outside of checking `instanceof` and throwing an error).

```
var Dialog = function() {};
Dialog.prototype.open = function() {
  var open = this;
  // how do ensure "this" is always the Dialog
  console.log(open);
};
```

With this code, any user can mistakenly "coerce" the context to be incorrect. For example:

```
var pointer = new Dialog().open;
pointer(); // "this" would become Window
```

I'm trying to find a way to handle this *internally* so that I don't have to throw an error or rely on the user to always do the right thing.

A user could always call `pointer.call(dialog)` but that means they need a separate pointer for the dialog, and this is a good example of a burden on the user rather than me, the author.

Comment: Do you intend to have multiple instances of `Dialog`? Do you want to allow the user to use an instance of `Dialog` directly? (`var d = new Dialog(); d.open();`)

Comment: This is not something your class/library should really be worrying about.  If the user incorrectly calls/invokes a method, that's their problem.  They should be using the language correctly for everything to function correctly.

Comment: Yes, there may be multiple instances, and I will allow the user to use an instance repeatedly.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm inclined to agree, this is more for my curiosity. If I can do something to easily handle this use-case I'd like to know. If my only solution is to throw an error, I shall.

Answer (score 1):

It's really screwy and kind of ruins the performance gains you get with prototypical inheritance but you could explicitly bind each of the functions within the constructor.

```js
function log(obj) {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerText += obj.toString() + '\n';
}

function Dialog() {
  this.open = this.open.bind(this);
}
Dialog.prototype.open = function() {
  log(this);
};
Dialog.prototype.toString = function() {
  return '[object Dialog]';
};

var d = new Dialog();
d.open();
var open = d.open;
open();
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

This would create unique function objects for each method of each instance of `Dialog` but technically it would work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really prevent this using prototyping. The `bind` suggestion by Mike C does indeed do the deed, but it is basically a very elaborate/expensive way to use the decorator pattern, which does solve the scoping issue:

```
function Dialog() {
    var dialog = this;

    dialog.open = function() {
        console.log(dialog, this);
    };
}

var d = new Dialog();
d.open();

var open = d.open();
open();
```

Keep in mind that this approach is much less memory efficient than the `prototype` example in your question, so never use it if you have a lot of instances.